# Disassembling: How can I retrieve the address of a module's global variable via a function?

Tags: c++, assembly, reverse-engineering

```
const char* BotArgs[4]
bool UseBotArgs
```

Knowing this function's address, is it possible to retrieve the address of these global variables as well? If yes, I would also like to know how to get the offsets of them. Thanks!

[image: IDA Disassembler: mp.dll]
[image: IDA Disassembler: mp.dll & cs.so (code)]

Comment: To me your question is unclear. A bit more context would be good. BTW: C or C++?

Comment: Can you post the assembly as text, please? It helps others find your answer, amongst other things. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2):

You can read the addresses directly from the machine code.
For example, your `mov Str, eax` instruction is A3 **78 E3 0F 10**.
This is little-endian for 0x100FE378.

If you look at the next three mov calls, they assign to addresses 0x100FE380 through 0x100FE384.

So `BotArgs = fn+7` and `UseBotArgs = fn+37`.